# Asp.Net Core Web Api bug? "Put" cannot got value for the second parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a `Put` action. The Http request value cannot be passed to the second parameter.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody]DPost value) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"id: {id} value.MyId: {value.MyId}"); // id: B161 value.MyId:
    return Ok(value); // breakpoint here - id has value but value.MyId is null?
}
```

The following is the definition of the class.

```
public class DPost
{
    [Key]
    public String MyId { get; set; }
}
```

The following shows the raw Http requests.

```
PUT http://localhost:5001/api/D2/B161 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8082/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"id":"B161","value":{"myId":"B161"}}
```

And its response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 18:29:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 12

{"myId":null}
```

Is it a bug of Asp.net core? I also tried to change the parameter `value` to a simple type `int?` and changed the Http request and it still got null.

Comment: MyId should probably be case sensitive, just like in your json object, so it should be myId.

Comment: Tried to change the http request to `MyId` and it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

***Wrong answer: `value.Id` actually is assigned to first value `{id:"first", value:{id: "second"}}`. It should got "second". Is it a bug?***

I found a solution by changing the class `DPost` to:

```
public class DPost
{
    [Key]
    public String Id { get; set; }
}
```

Why? Does it need to match the first parameter case insensitively?

Comment: Maybe because: "By default, the Entity Framework interprets a property that's named ID as the primary key." But actually [Key] should do the same.

Comment: It's not right, `value.Id` actually is assigned to value of parameter 'id' of put.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `value.Id` got the value of the first parameter of `Put()` instead of the Id value it should get. `{id:"it got this one", value:{id: "instead of this one"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Add `[FromBody]` like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Put(string id, [FromBody]DPost value)
```

It tells the engine to retrieve the object from the body of the request.

Comment: I see the Json object you are passing is different than the class you declared. Did you try to pass only {"myId":"B161"} in the payload?

Comment: The difference is only the first letter, one is uppercase and one is lowercase. I tried to make them the same but not help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the case of MyId to the following:

```
public class DPost
{
    [Key]
    public String myId { get; set; }
}
```

to match the json object:

```
{"id":"B161","value":{"myId":"B161"}}
```

Comment: I changed "myId" in the json object to "MyId" and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your parameter this way:

```
{"id":"B161","myId":"B161"}
```